# Testing a furnace transfer switch, watt meter shows extremely low usage

Tags: electrical, wiring, furnace, meter, transfer-switch

I just installed a Reliance furnace transfer switch model TF151W to my main circuit panel.  I tried to test it by running an extension cord from another outlet to the transfer switch.  I put the P3 International P4460 Kill A Watt EZ Electricity Usage Monitor in the line to test the watt consumption of my hot air furnace.

After switching from Line to Generator and cranking up the heat, I noted the wattage was only 3.7 watts?  Is this because the common neutral is not switched?  If I was to connect the Honda EU2000I 2000 Watt inverter generator would I have any problems?

Comment: What model is your furnace?

Comment: Low capacity furnace; no problem.  Blowers, for such, are typically rated at 1/3 or 1/2 HP (Max SS draw about 400 watts).  Larger furnaces may trip the circuit when they try to start the blower, due to the surge current.

Comment: It is a Tech-4 True Blue 90 MOD USA 054NH3R, But with a 1/3 hp blower I would think it would draw 400 or a bit more in watts?  Why would the meter read only 3.7 watts?

Comment: @AndrewFischer -- is the blower kicking in?

Comment: yes it is working normally

Comment: With a clean filter and open dampers, a *running* 1/3 HP blower typically draws 50 to 170 watts (250 watts, is for worst-case scenario. More than that and motor safeties trip.)  Since you are only seeing 3.7 watts, it's likely that your hookup is not as stated or your *Kill-A-Watt* up and died. ... Post pics of your setup.

Comment: Also it's possible that your preexisting wiring is off and I don't know how a *Kill-A-Watt* reacts to that. Use one of those circuit tester plugs to make sure that you don't have a neutral/ground swap or similar.

Comment: You're only wiring the Hot through the Kill-a-Watt?  Try running the neutral through too.

Comment: @Brock Adams - I tested the watt meter on a CFL and it read 17.3 Watts so the meter is still working.  I tested the outlet I was testing with and it is wired correctly.

Comment: @Harper - The Furnace transfer switch only switches the hot, I would have to add a switch for the neutral, and I am not qualified for that;)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need to switch the neutral.  Photograph your setup.  Is there any chance that the blower for this furnace is on a different circuit? And you tested with [one of these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6cAD.jpg)?  And got exactly 2 yellow lights?

Comment: Brock, i don't have the ability to take a picture (right now, maybe over the weekend) but I installed it like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-vnaBXdvHQ,  I do have a separate ground and neutral bus bar, so the ground and neutral are not in the same bar.  The outlet I'm using to test the transfer switch has just the 2 lights.  I did notice the circuit breaker for the outlet is on the "other" main in the circuit panel.  But I wouldn't think that would matter.  I'm trying to contact International to see if the Kill-a-Watt meter needs the neutral switched.  Thanks again!

Comment: No, the Kill-A-Watt does not need the neutral switched. You plugged it into an existing socket that tested as good, then plugged the test extension cord into it. That's all it needs. Which "side" of the main panel does not matter as long as furnace is 110V, not 220V. At this point, either: (A) the Xfer switch wiring is off, (B) the xfer switch is not actually switching away from line when you set it to "Gen" (defective switch) or, (C) **most likely**, the xfer switch is not really hooked up to the circuit that powers the blower. Also, there are no aux or booster fans in your HVAC, right?

Comment: There are no other fans or blowers.  I did a test where I was running the furnace on "Gen" and shut off the "line" at the circuit breaker, and the furnace kept running (flame and all).  This would lead me to think the switch is working and the blower is running on the same line as the electronics. I just confirmed this as there is only one line going to the furnace and I opened the emergency switch on the furnace and there are only 3 conductors (switched hot and pass through neutral and ground)
I'm waiting on a response from Kill-A-Watt.

Comment: With the blower running on "Gen", unplug the gen extension cord.  Does the blower instantly stop?  Your previous test would give the same result if the xfer switch was wired to some other circuit and not the furnace.  Also, just in case, verify that the voltage at the furnace is 110V and not 220V.

Comment: I just performed your test, and with the blower on in "Gen" mode, disconnecting the extension cord immediately shut off the blower.  With only 3 conductors going into the furnace i can only test the switched black wire (at the emergency switch) and it was 120 volts.  I have yet to get a response from Kill-A-Watt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the tests you ran (see comments above), your setup is correct.

The *Kill A Watt EZ* should show a reasonable reading, BUT it appears that that kind of device requires balanced current.
So, because the furnace neutral current is not flowing through the *Kill A Watt*, it does not compute a valid power based on the current and voltage it does see. (Note that the meter is seeing a "ground fault" from its perspective.)

EG:
          [image: Meter limitations]

This is an apparent limitation of this model of meter; your setup is correct.

---

To determine the furnace's power draw, if you don't trust the label plate :), and, since you've access to the wiring at the furnace, measure the current and voltage there with standard AC meters.

Multiply the voltage and current to get KVA.  The KVA will be slightly more than the actual power used (thanks to power factor), but your generator needs to be able to supply about twice that KVA anyway (allows for motor start).

Since your furnace has a 1/3 HP blower (max 250 watts, steady state), your Honda 2000 Watt generator should be just fine to power your furnace.

Comment: Thank you, You have been very helpful!  I was thinking the neutral loop and the neutral straight to the circuit panel would cause a problem with the meter.  I am going to pursue this further with the Kill-A-Watt manufacturer.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you hear anything good from the KAW people, you can post it in a comment or self-answer here.

Comment: I would say it's the meter working as intended.  I'd also say **move the Kill-a-watt so it's on the switched side, or reroute the neutral so it goes through the Kill-a-Watt.**  That shouldn't be THAT hard; neutrals are **required** to travel with their companion hots, so that the magnetic fields cancel each other out.  Otherwise you can get eddy current heating in places you do not want that.

Comment: @Harper, this is no requirement to switch the neutral here, nor any logical or practical reason to.  This scenario occurs ***only*** during the kind of *momentary* testing that the OP did, whereby testing the switch from another AC socket instead of a generator.  Using an actual generator, the neutral is paired with the hot.  In the test scenario, there's a benign ground loop.  Other than this kind of meter, there is no drawback and the configuration is extremely temporary.

Comment: You wouldn't switch the neutral. I said to make sure the neutral also loops through the Kill-a-Watt, so that it works properly.  This could happen on either side of the switch. Easily done, lop a 3-prong extension cord in half and now you have cheater cords. That's how I test hardwired things with a KaW.

Comment: @Harper, this is not "easily done". You'd have to alter the home's wiring to "loop the neutral". That is NOT recommended nor necessary for the OP's purposes.  The easiest thing to do is just fire up the generator, plug the KAW into that and test the furnace. Meter problem worked around.